# Formar una expresion regular

Tags: regex

Estoy tratando de formar una expresión regular para una ubicación en mi proyecto con next.js, la url que quiero seria esta: `/_next/static/tjZg5zImQlg8MALugtfP7/pages/_app.js`

siendo esta parte `/tjZg5zImQlg8MALugtfP7/` la que quiero ponerla como expresion regular, ya que cada vez que hago run build se genera una nueva carpeta con otro identificador.

Actualmente probe con este `/_next/static/[a-zA-Z0-9]/pages/_app.js` y no funciona.

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba con esto: `/_next/static/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/pages/_app[.]js\b` Ejemplo: https://regex101.com/r/zljtFp/1/

Answer (score 2):

El problema de tu expresión es que no has usado un multiplicador para tu selección de caracteres.

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` sólo selecciona **un** caracter que pueda ser de la *a* a la *z*, mayúscula o minúscula o número.

Añadiendo el multiplicador `+` consigues capturar *uno o más* caracteres de los que tienes entre corchetes.

En cuanto al `.` es mejor escaparlo (`\.`), ya que en realidad en expresiones regulares significa *cualquier caracter*.

`/_next/static/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/pages/_app\.js` sería una expresión más adecuada.